# Medical insurance at border control on visa-free travel to Belarus

Tags: customs-and-immigration, insurance, belarus

[It is still uncertain](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/102542/is-the-insurance-by-my-credit-card-company-sufficient-to-visit-belarus-without-a) whether my credit card insurance works as a medical insurance for visa-free travel to Belarus, so I'm going to prepare for signing in the insurance at the Minsk airport.

However, I guess that the medical insurance must be done before you pass through the immigration; otherwise no one would check your insurance. But I also feel that there is no ATM until you get through the immigration.

So it is unlikely that I could not have Belarusian currency, unless I obtain it in my destination airport in advance. But the rate must be pretty bad so I would rather avoid it.

So, my questions are:

- How much does the insurance cost? I travel for 5 days (4 nights).
- Can I use my credit card (either Amex or Visa)?
- If it is only in cash, are other currencies acceptable, including Euro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cost of insurance is given on the [website of MSQ airport](http://airport.by/en/Compulsory-medical-insurance): for 5 days it would cost you **6 euro**.

Speaking about cash, you can purchase your insurance certificate both with BYN, RUR and with USD and EUR, so there is no need to worry here.

Speaking about cards, *I cannot give you fully reliable information*, so, please, keep my words only as a general guidance, not as a 100% proven source.
I had no experience of purchasing insurance on arrival in Belarus, but taking into considerations my decades of living in Belarus and knowledge of card acceptance there, I can assume with a high probability that cards **will be** accepted in the insurance office. And as well, I am as sure as a gun that AmEx **will not** be accepted. Neither in the airport, nor on the other territory of Belarus (despite very rare places).

**P.S.** You feel it right, there will be no ATM until arrival hall. See [my blue marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI1bi.jpg) on airport scheme. The full scheme [is here](http://airport.by/sites/default/files/images/map/f1b.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

The general practice is:

you apply for a visa with a certificate / confirmation from your insurance people that they cover Belarus and it's no less than 10k;

if you are on a visa-free mode, you will have to present this certificate (or just your policy) at the airport passports control;

at the local police station (not required if on a 5-day visa-free thing) you might need to have a policy with serial No and other related info to put into their database, even a translation might be required;

Conclusion: **have a conventional insurance policy or the coverage confirmation, even if you have to buy it only for Belarus or buy one on arrival**.

A

Comment: P.S. Arrival gates 3-4 of the MSQ airport now have ATMs before the passports control.